# Grails functional test dependency injection

Tags: testing, grails, dependency-injection, functional-programming

I am quite new to Grails, but I am using this plugin for functional testing:
http://www.grails.org/Grails%20Functional%20Testing
I am wondering how to inject a service such as the messageSource or or the applicationContext so I can have access to different resources. A simple example would be that I want to write a functional test to check if the text on the website is equal to the message string in the messages.properties file. Right now I cant seem to find an out of the box way of doing that. Can you advice on something? Also is that the best functional testing framework for grails since its quite limited?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Geb](http://grails.org/plugin/geb) instead it is a good framework that has nice support and good docs. But the one items to remember is that functional tests are running against the full stack so some tests you may find work better as integration or unit tests.

Comment: I cant seem to find the documentation for the Geb plugin at all?

Comment: Ill have a look thanks! I cant mark it as answer though since it doesnt really answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the remote control plugin in grails to modify your grails application on the fly. It uses the groovy remote control mechanism and serializes results for functional tests

Comment: I guess that would work but since im running the tests on the same machine with the same codebase, why isnt there a simple way to access the application "locally" rather than using this remote control appraoch ?

Comment: It's a good question. Remote control plugin is the best solution for me because it is more future proof --- imagine moving to jenkins slaves and then all your tests fail because they expect everything on the same machine. There are hacks you can use to modify the same machine, such as using a fixture controller, etc, but Remote Control keeps things isolated pretty well.

Comment: Best practices suggest testing against a deployed War for functional / ui tests. Since you could run in dev mode, resources plugin might work well, but in prod mode things break. I suggest watching around minute 26 of http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/groovy-grails/productive-grails-functional-testing for rationale.